# Optimizing Nginx

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I'm using Nginx as RPS and have issue with that the server can not handle more than ~ 100 request / s. If a single IP sends that much request Nginx will serve everybody 502 error.

Here is what I have.

A dedicated machine with this specs,

100 mbps (both directions).
Dual Core CPU
5 GB Memory
Windows Server 2008 R2

Apache, PHP (as module) & MySQL at the back handeling Dynamic content.
Nginx at front and passes requests to Apache.

Every page on the server is dynamically generated and well optimized, No MySQL load, etc... Every page is under 50KB size.

Respons time / load time under 0.6s.

So everything is snappy until someone opens whatever software and sends requests to the server, when request rate is about 100req/s it begins to send 502 error. The requests never gets to Apache. so it's not an Apache issue.

Would't that server handle much more?

Here is what Nginx CONF Looks like,

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  K:/logs/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        off;
    server_tokens off;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 50m;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    root   K:/website/domain.com/;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
           expires 365d;
        }

    ## send request back to Apache ##
    location / {
     proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
     proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}

}
```

Appreciate any help and suggestions.

Comment: offtopic. this is not a programming question - it's server optimization. Try serverfault and/or the webmasters SE sites.

Comment: Sorry, can some one please move the topic to ServerFault.

Comment: @D_Guy13: I'll ask a mod for you for _ServerFault_, it looks like a good fit.

Comment: Are you running fastcgi? if so, can we see your buffer value

Comment: No, not running FastCGI.

Comment: After doing some tests and compairing both static and dynamic content. The server could handle  3,918 successful hits in 47.80 seconds wihtout issue (Static) and 1,579 successful hits in 16.07 seconds (Dynamic). This means that it could be a Apache / MySQL / PHP Issue, mm, Nginx is giving status 499 for a lot requests also.

Comment: I flagged this nearly two days ago as a candidate for ServerFault, but I think mods must be pushed for time. It's a good question otherwise, so I'll leave it open for now.

Comment: Ah, closed by a mod and not moved - sorry @D_Guy13!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 502 status is returned when the upstream server (gateway) can't handle the request (in time), so this is quite likely an Apache issue.

As others have suggested you should take a closer look at the configuration of Apache itself, specifically the [`MaxRequestWorkers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) (2.4) or [`MaxClients`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) (2.2) setting.

> Nginx is giving status 499 for a lot requests also.

This means that the client (browser) closed the connection before the response could be sent; most likely, this is caused by a slow upstream, again pointing to Apache.

Answer (score 1):

> The requests never gets to Apache. so it's not an Apache issue.

Yes it is an Apache problem - most likely you've reached maxclients on the Apache and it's refusing any more connections.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx on Windows is not officially recommended for production:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html ; if your host has to be Windows, you might as well get better results by running nginx inside of a VM.

Comment: Actually, nothing is really recommended for production on Windows ;-)